# Why is ApprovalRequest.Comments appearing as blank for an email template upon initial submission?

Tags: email-template, approval-process

I have a standard email template on an opportunity object with {!ApprovalRequest.Comments} as a field I want filled out on the email template. This is sent on the initial approval request. The field just shows up as blank despite having a value in the comments when submitted.
Strange thing is that ApprovalRequest.Comments works fine for the rejection email template, and populates the field there. Just not on the initial submission stage of the approval process. Any ideas?